# GPU accelerated compositing in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, gpu, compositing

I am running Ubuntu 19.10 with Intel graphics (i7-8565U) and Google Chrome 80.0.3987.122.

I enabled flags `#enable-gpu-rasterization`, `#enable-zero-copy`, `#ignore-gpu-blacklist`. I also enabled `#tint-gl-composited-content` to see if GPU acceleration works. However nothing is tinted. It is quite strange because I read that Chrome on Linux has GPU accelerated compositing enabled by default. How can I enable it?